# Nginx reverse proxy to dockerized angular app cannot load assets

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

When I try to access my dockerized angular app through the Nginx reverse proxy the page does not fully load because all included scripts are not found (404).

It loads fine when I access it directly on the exposed docker port at localhost:4200.

Base URL is set to `<base href="/">`

For example, there is a script:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-AVJWFAVY.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">`

```
example.com/styles-AVJWFAVY.css -> 404

localhost:4200/styles-AVJWFAVY.css -> OK
```

**Nginx** (reverse proxy)

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        http2 on;

        server_name example.com;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem;

        location / {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:4200;
        }
}

# HTTP redirect to HTTPS
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name .example.com;

        location / {
                return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
        }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest as build
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY ./ /usr/local/app/
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/app/browser /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 4200
```

**nginx.conf** (inside Docker container)

```
server {
  listen 4200;
  listen [::]:4200;
  server_name localhost;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```

I start docker with: `sudo docker run -d --name personal-website -p 4200:4200 personal-website`

Comment: I also tried `<base href="./">` and adding a slash at the end of `proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;`

Comment: Hi. Does `https://example.com/styles-AVJWFAVY.css` work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is the path from which these assets are being served versus how they are being requested.
From what you have described, accessing the Angular app directly through the Docker port works fine, which suggests that the problem lies in how requests are being forwarded by Nginx.

You have already set `<base href="/">`, which is correct for most setups. That should mean that all assets are requested relative to the domain root. Try to add a trailing slash to the [`proxy_pass` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) to make sure the path is correctly appended:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;
}
```

And, to handle the static assets correctly, you might want to [add some headers in the proxy configuration](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#passing-request-headers) to make sure the host and protocol are correctly forwarded to the Angular app:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4200/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```

After making the changes to the Nginx reverse proxy configuration, make sure you reload Nginx to apply these changes (`sudo nginx -s reload`).
And verify there are no caching issues. Browsers sometimes cache the 404 responses. Try accessing the app in incognito mode or clearing your browser's cache.
Then check the Nginx access and error logs for any additional clues on why the assets might be failing to load.